# Oracle Query with Schema in main table

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

I'm finding a lot of similar articles, but none quite covering what I need.   I didn't design the table nor can I modify it.   I am limited to a Read Only role.

I have an Info table in a root schema.   Let's call it SchemaRoot.   In the info table it contains a field with addition schema's for each record.

Info.RootSchema

| ID | SchemaName | ProjectOwner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project1 | Bob |
| 2 | Project2 | Larry |

Then all the project info is in it's own Schema.

ProjectInfo.Project1 or ProjectInfo.Project2

| ProjectDetail1 | ProjectDetail2 | ProjectDetail3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blah | Blah | Blah |
| Blah | Blah | Blah |

I need to be able to query the the RootSchema and SubSchema's in one query.

So I need something that'll give me.

| ProjectOwner | ProjectDetail1 | ProjectDetail2 | ProjectDetail3 |

for every project in Info.RootSchema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me, but I'm not sure we speak Oracle here. What exactly do you call a "schema"? In an Oracle database, we create a *user* who then creates its tables, views, procedures etc., so user + all its objects represent a *schema*. I think that this is what you're trying to say.

There is one "master" schema (`root`), while every project has its own schema (`project1`, `project2`, etc.).

If any user wants to access data owned by another user - for example, in your case it is the  `root` user who will select data owned by users named `project1`, `project2`, etc. - then these users have to **grant** certain privileges to `root`.

Therefore, you'd

```
connect project1/its_password
grant select on projectinfo to root;

connect project2/its_password
grant select on projectinfo to root;
```

Then, connect as `root` and access data owned by other users either by preceding table name with its owner (e.g. `project1.projectinfo` - **not** vice versa, which is what you posted - if I got you right), or by creating synonyms as

```
create synonym project1_projectinfo for project1.projectinfo;
create synonym project2_projectinfo for project2.projectinfo;
```

For sample data:

```
SQL> select * from info;

SCHEMANA PROJE
-------- -----
Project1 Bob
Project2 Larry

SQL> select * From project1_projectinfo;

PROJECTD PROJECTD
-------- --------
1 info 1 1 info 2
1 info 3 1 info 4

SQL> select * from project2_projectinfo;

PROJECTD PROJECTD
-------- --------
2 info 6 2 info 7
```

you'd get

```
SQL> select r.projectowner, a.projectdetail1, a.projectdetail2
  2  from info r cross join project1_projectinfo a
  3  where r.schemaname = 'Project1'
  4  union all
  5  select r.projectowner, b.projectdetail1, b.projectdetail2
  6  from info r cross join project2_projectinfo b
  7  where r.schemaname = 'Project2';

PROJE PROJECTD PROJECTD
----- -------- --------
Bob   1 info 1 1 info 2
Bob   1 info 3 1 info 4
Larry 2 info 6 2 info 7

SQL>
```

---

That's pretty much *hardcoded* solution. Can it be done "dynamically"? Yes; one option is to create a function which composes `select` statement to be used as a source for ref cursor. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(10000);
  5    rc sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select schemaname, projectowner from info) loop
  8      l_str := l_str ||
  9        'select ' || chr(39) || cur_r.projectowner || chr(39) || ' as projectowner, ' ||
 10        'projectdetail1, projectdetail2 from ' || cur_r.schemaname ||'_projectinfo' ||
 11        ' union all ';
 12    end loop;
 13    l_str := regexp_replace(l_str, ' union all $');
 14    open rc for l_str;
 15    return rc;
 16  end;
 17  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

PROJE PROJECTD PROJECTD
----- -------- --------
Bob   1 info 1 1 info 2
Bob   1 info 3 1 info 4
Larry 2 info 6 2 info 7


SQL>
```

---

If that's not it, then I obviously didn't understand you speaking Oracle.

Comment: Pretty sure you are 100%.   I've been trying to avoid functions or dynamic tsql.   Mainly since I can't use it as read only.  I was hoping there was a simpler way that I just didn't know.    I'm currently using tSQL to create a result set with the strings and building my querys that way.   There are close to 2500 records in the main table, so it takes a really long time to run that many querys.   This is not my DB.  This is the back end for a much larger program.   I'm just trying to find a why to glean some intel off it, and the app don't provide that sort of intel.